# Why is the <li> element that contains <a> element with 15px padding not as big as the <a> element?

Tags: html, css

Why is the `<li>` element that contains `<a>` element with 15px padding not as big as the `<a>` element? Shouldn't it have height equal to that of the `<a>` element?

The `<a>` element has a height of 47px if we include the padding, however, the parent `<li>` element only has 18px. Shouldn't it have 47px height as well?

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Hey</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Hey</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to set `display: block` for `a` element.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Hey</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Hey</a></li>
</ul>
```